# How to update org-mode default template?

Tags: org-mode

I use `C-c C-e` -> `#` -> `default` to insert the default template for `org-export`. But some of the value of the options are not what I want. How could I modify the default template (change values or add more options)?

Comment: Looking at the source for `org-export-insert-default-template`, the `default` template seems to be handled separately, and its content is specified by the variable `org-export-options-alist`.